# Security.vcl varnish configuration.?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I Have configure varnish. Now i want to configure security.vcl on it. I am following this link  http://www.slideshare.net/kimlindholm/varnish-configuration-step-by-step.

i've configure each step carefully. But when I try to visit on links provided on slides no. 13 of above link. I can't get desired result. Please tell me where is a problem?

Comment: Please tell us a bit more: what error do you get? I always use vcl.reload if I change my vcl in order to see the line where the parsing goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat hard to guess what is wrong with your setup, but I would recommend you start with one of the newer version of Security VCL.

https://github.com/comotion/security.vcl - you might also have some success with filing the issue there.